# How to use -f file existence comparison operator in echo in shell script?

Tags: shell

```
#/bin/sh

echo "Please enter file name:"
read FILENAME
d=[ -f $FILENAME ]
echo $d
```

This doesn't work. `-f: command not found`. Okay sounds correct there.

Another variation that *seems* to be working, but instead in the console a newline is added.

```
#/bin/sh

echo "Please enter file name:"
read FILENAME
d=$(test -f $FILENAME )
echo $d
```

But I tried to test the value of `$d` and it is neither `\n` nor `"0"` nor `1`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't see any output because `$d` is empty, so you are effectively echoing an empty string (with the trailing newline added by `echo`). `$d` is empty because `test` doesn't return any output to be assigned to it. Instead when you work with `test`, the important thing is the exit status, which you can capture with `$?`:

```
echo "Please enter file name:"
read FILENAME
test -f $FILENAME
echo $?
```

Alternatively you can use this as an expression in other conditions:

```
read -p "Please enter file name: " FILENAME
[[ -f "$FILENAME" ]] && echo "This is a valid file" || echo "Not a valid file"
```